# how to put my photos from database inside an array to display via explode

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, explode, implode

I am trying to show all my photos from my database in relation to the user id where they are stored.
If i do something like this it obviously works to display the text in an array however i need to know how to replace that text with my images.

```
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

Here is how I am storing the photos. they are stored in my uploads folder of the project as well as in the database under `$row->photos`if i print `<h3>$row->photos<h3>`to my site it will bring up all of the photos that i wish to show, so i do know they are there.

this is how im storing them and you can see where they are moved to my uploads folder.

```
 $ads = new Listings;
$images = $request->file('photos');
$count = 0;
if($request->file('photos')){
foreach($images as $item){
if($count < 6){
$var = date_create();
$date = date_format($var, 'Ymd');
$imageName = $date.'_'.$item->getClientOriginalName();
$item->move(public_path().'/uploads/',$imageName);
$url = URL::to("/").'/uploads/'.$imageName;
$arr[] = $url;
$count++;
}
}
$image = implode(",", $arr);
$ads->photos = $image;
return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Listing published successfully');
```

here is the code used for the view I want to put the photos in

```
public function view(Request $request, $id){
$ads = DB::table('listings')
->select ('listings.id', 'photos', 'description', 'year', 'make', 'model', 'price', 'city', 'state', 'email')
->where(['id' => $id])
->get();
$output = '';
if($ads->count() > 0){
return view('users.posted.postedads', ['id'=>$id, 'ads'=>$ads]);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the code you are currently using to retrieve your photos?

Comment: added the code  to the post @Don'tPanic

Comment: It looks like the `photos` field is a comma separated list of image URLs.  Your `view()` code just retrieves a record including that field.  So this should be exactly like your `explode()` example?  Because you use `get()` in your DB query, the result is a collection, not a record (if you use `first()`, you'll just take the first record, and considering you're selecting by ID there should be only 1).  So to get the record you need to do eg `$ad = $ads->first();`.  Then the photos field is just a string you can explode: `print_r (explode(" ",$ad->photos));`.

Comment: I highly recommend taking a few minutes to read the relevant sections of the docs.  For eg the [Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results) section of the Database guide is only 4 sentences long, and clearly answers your question, including simple example code.  Also check out [the Eloquent section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent), you can simplify and improve your code if you add some models and relationships.  When in doubt, read the docs!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly

```
@foreach 

(explode(',', $row->photos) as $row->photos)
<img src="{{$row->photos}}" style="width:75%; height:75%; align-content: center;">

@endforeach
```